# Neo4j use 2 column values for relationship in the middle of 2 nodes

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am working with some email data in neo4j.  Right now I am just a csv and loading the data in, creating nodes with the `From` and `FileHash` columns.

```
   From             Outcome    FileHash
0  sender1@sdf.com  aborted    sd65f4a6s5d3s456a54
1  sender2@lkj.com  delivered  asd35433a54d5f453a4 
2  sender4@ask.com  delivered  as663468a635d4888d1
```

Current code:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///sessions/parsed_message_amp.csv") AS row
WITH row WHERE NOT row.FileHash IS null //for emails that dont contain attachments
MERGE (a:Sender { name: row.From})
MERGE (b:Attachment { name: row.FileHash})
MERGE (a)-[:SENT]->(b)
```

This gives me just the relationship `SENT`.  I would like to use the Outcome field for the relationship so that if the `Outcome` was aborted it would say `aborted` instead of `SENT`, and if it was delivered it would say `delivered`.  How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: I'm a little unclear - do you want a property on the relationship called 'outcome' that contains either 'aborted' or 'delivered', or do you want to create different relationship types based on whether outcome is 'aborted' or 'delivered'?

Comment: I added an image of what it would look like if there were only 3 rows in the csv @Pablissimo

Comment: Hopefully the image in the answer I posted looks familiar then :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [APOC](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/#_installation_with_neo4j_desktop) for this - you may need to install it, but if you're using Neo4j Desktop [it's only a couple of clicks](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/#_installation_with_neo4j_desktop). You can't create dynamically typed relationships in Cypher, but with APOC you can use `apoc.merge.relationship` and just pull in the Outcome property as the relationship name.

The `WITH` here is just setting up some test data to simulate your `LOAD CSV` call - simply replace it with your first line.

```
WITH [
{From: 'sender1@sdf.com', Outcome: 'aborted', FileHash: 'sd65f4a6s5d3s456a54'},
{From: 'sender2@lkj.com', Outcome: 'delivered', FileHash: 'asd35433a54d5f453a4'},
{From: 'sender4@ask.com', Outcome: 'delivered', FileHash: 'as663468a635d4888d1'}] as records
UNWIND records as row
MERGE (a: Sender { name: row.From })
MERGE (b: Attachment { name: row.FileHash })
WITH a, b, row
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome, {}, {}, b) YIELD rel
RETURN a, b
```

You might want to upper-case the `row.Outcome` before using it as a relationship name to make it a bit more standard, up to you.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help @Pablissimo